# Simplifying SQL self-join query

Tags: mysql, sql, common-table-expression

I have a table like this:

| name | value | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ACME | 10.45 | 2020-01-01 |
| ACME | 10.88 | 2020-02-01 |
| ACME | 10.22 | 2020-03-01 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| ACME | 9.244 | 2022-04-04 |

What I'd like to do is get the average `value` for a date range (say the first 3 tuples) and compare them to the value with the latest `date` for a `name` (say the last tuple).

I am unable to create a SQL view or stored procedure, so have reverted to a CTE, but this has become horribly complex and slow. E.g. (my own SQL differs so not sure if the below would compile)

```sql
with averages as (
    select avg(value) from table where date between '2020-01-01' and '2020-03-01' group by name
), 
latest_date as (
    select name, max(date) as max_date from table group by name
) 
select a.name from averages a 
join latest_date b on a.name=b.name 
join table c on b.max_date = c.date
```

Expected output:

| name | average_for_range | latest_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ACME | (average value for date range) | 9.244 |

Is there a simpler/easier way to do this?

Comment: Please edit the question to contain the actual SQL you are using, along with the actual result.  Include the CREATE TABLE statement with all available indexes.  Also review/show the explain plan associated with the actual SQL as a starting point.

Comment: That doesn't look "horriblhy complex" to me.

Comment: `averages` just selects an average, there's no `name` column, so how is `a.name` supposed to work? What name should be returned if the rows in the date range have different names?

Comment: Why does the `latest_date` CTE select `name`? That won't select the name with the latest date, it will just select an arbitrary name from the table. `c.name` contains the name from that row, maybe that's what you wanted instead of `a.name`?

Comment: Your example has only one "name" (ACME).  If you are asking about multiple names in the same query, it is more complex.  Please add to the example _or_ state that there ins only one "name".

Comment: appreciate the comments/replies. @RickJames multiple names, yes.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't see a simpler way. My answer is only about execution speed hence.

I'd rewrite this a little in order to get the last values in the CTE already.

```
with averages as (
  select name, avg(value) as avg_value
  from my table
  where date between date '2020-01-01' and date '2020-03-01'
  group by name
), 
latest_date as (
  select name, value as max_date_value
  from mytable
  where (name, date) in (select name, max(date) from mytable group by name)
) 
select name, averages.avg_value, latest_date.max_date_value
from averages
join latest_date using (name)
order by name;
```

For the DBMS to quickly find the rows with the maximum date per name, I'd provide the following index:

```
create index idx1 on mytable (name, date);
```

And to help it get the data in the given date range, I'd add:

```
create index idx2 on mytable (date, name);
```

Comment: appreciate the answer, thanks